# Is it possible to truncate a URL using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am trying to find a solution to truncating the URL instead of showing - 
http://mywebsite.com/main/android.php?dir=.%2Fandroid
it should show: http://mywebsite.com/main/android/android.php

Comment: use htaccess for that

Comment: yes, it's possible :) you may google it

Comment: is it possible to trunkate all the url's in .htaccess? cause i have many sub directories whose url shows in the same way.

Comment: I just want to hide query from URL

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you really want to that in PHP. What you can do is using the .htaccess file to provide such a url transformation.

Otherwise you could do something like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['dir'])) {
    $dir = $_GET['dir'];
    header('Location: ' . $dir . '/android.php');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I need to trunkate the url's of all my subdirectories also

Comment: I just want to hide the query from url